# Hiding an element from the controller by accessing ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input and a list of tags. The list contains the `ng-show` directed wired up to the model in the input.

```
  <div id="tag-search">
    <input type="text" ng-model="tagQuery" />
    <ul ng-show="tagQuery">
      <li ng-repeat="t in tags | filter:tagQuery">
        <button type="button">{{t.name}}</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Like you'd expect, when the input is empty the list isn't displayed. When you start typing the list pops into view.

**I'd like to also hide the list of tags** when the user clicks anywhere on the page. So I have an `ng-click` directive on the container div for the page. The `ng-click` is connected to this function in my controller:

```
$scope.closeFormModals = function() {
  // What goes here to hide the tag list?
};
```

I have tried three things, but none of them hide the tag list:

1. `$scope.tagQuery = false;`
2. `$scope.tagQuery = undefined;`
3. `angular.element("#tag-search input").val('');`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/niftygrifty/VFSfg/5/)

Here's are links to the repo with all the code:

[angular stuff](https://github.com/tygriffin/LessonNotes/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/lesson_notes/angular)

[view](https://github.com/tygriffin/LessonNotes/blob/master/app/views/layouts/lesson_notes/_notes_form.html)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: are you shure the event will be called? Because `$scope.tagQuery = false;` should do it. Please show us your complete html and the corresponding angular controller

Comment: I just added a link to the repo in the question.

Comment: @niftygrifty which is the corresponding view to the NotesCtrl?

Comment: Sorry about that! [It's here](https://github.com/tygriffin/LessonNotes/blob/master/app/views/layouts/lesson_notes/_notes_form.html)

Comment: Here's a fiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/niftygrifty/VFSfg/5/

Comment: I dont see any problem with the code, all runs fine. May you assign an empty string to $scope.tagQuery instead of boolean value false, so you dont get the "false" text in the textarea. (`$scope.tagQuery = '';`). Take in consideration that the div with the ng-click-directive is height and width enough to cover the whole screen, otherwise the click will not be recognized if the user click outside the div

Comment: May its better to use AngularJS' [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directive for the input field here. `<input type="text" ng-model="tagQuery" ng-blur="closeFormModals()">`

Comment: @stevuu wrote a really good answer that I think was close to being correct, but it's gone now... According to him, the `tagQuery`s in the view and controller may live in different scopes. I'm logging out the `$scope.tagQuery` referenced in the controller on page clicks and it never changes no matter what I type in the search field. However, I'm not sure how to figure out in what scope the `tagQuery` referenced in the html view lives...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to prefix `$parent` to the ng-model referenced in the view, because anything referenced by ng-model gets stuck in isolated scope apparently.

```
<div id="tag-search">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.tagQuery" placeholder="Add tags"/>
    <ul ng-show="$parent.tagQuery" class="list-inline">
      <li ng-repeat="t in tags | filter:tagQuery">
        <button id="{{t.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addTag(t)">{{t.name}}</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[More info in this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1924)

Special thanks to @stevuu for leading me to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$scope.closeFormModels = function() {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.tagQuery = false;
  });
};
```

Comment: $scope.$apply is not necessary here. You only need it if you inform angular about scope changes from externer JS (e.g. jQuery Plugins)

Comment: That's what I thought, but why is updating tagQuery to false not updating the ng-show?

Comment: mayabe the click-event will not be called properly

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. I tried that as well as wrapping the `$scope.tagQuery = false` in `$timeout` to make sure the change gets included in the next digest.

Comment: @tschiela I put a `console.log` in the `closeFormModals` function and was set off, so I think the ng-click is set up okay.